# Mysql subquery result in "where" clause

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to execute mysql query like this?

```
select (select A from B where ... ) as C from D where C like ' ... '
```

I need to use the result of subquery in general "where" clause.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can wrap it in a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        select (select A from B where ... ) as C from D
     ) subq
WHERE 
    C like ' ... '
```

Comment: I think this should work, but I think I cannot use it for my purpose. I need to create something like "select field1, field2, sql3 as field3, field4, sql5 as field5 from table where field2 = ' ... ', field5 = ' ... '

Comment: @Eddie, yes you can use this. Just move the parts of the where clause that use the subquery derived field to the outer where clause.

Comment: Hm.. Can you please provide an example. How it should be? "select field1, sql2 field2 from `table` where field1 = '...' and field2 = '...'

Comment: ah, at last I understood how to use it) thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 16):

Have you read this?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

> A subquery is a SELECT statement within another statement.
>
> Starting with MySQL 4.1, all subquery forms and operations that the
>   SQL standard requires are supported, as well as a few features that
>   are MySQL-specific.
>
> Here is an example of a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

> In this
>   example, SELECT * FROM t1 ... is the outer query (or outer statement),
>   and (SELECT column1 FROM t2) is the subquery. We say that the subquery
>   is nested within the outer query, and in fact it is possible to nest
>   subqueries within other subqueries, to a considerable depth. A
>   subquery must always appear within parentheses.
>
> The main advantages of subqueries are:
>
> They allow queries that are structured so that it is possible to
>   isolate each part of a statement.
>
> They provide alternative ways to perform operations that would
>   otherwise require complex joins and unions.
>
> Many people find subqueries more readable than complex joins or
>   unions. Indeed, it was the innovation of subqueries that gave people
>   the original idea of calling the early SQL “Structured Query
>   Language.”
>
> Here is an example statement that shows the major points about
>   subquery syntax as specified by the SQL standard and supported in
>   MySQL:

Answer (score 3):

No not as illustrated; but you could run the query in both places. or create a temp table with those results and join them in making it available to the query..

`Select C from D inner join (Select A from B where...) C on C.1=D.1 where C like....`

Comment: I thought about running query in both places, yes... the easiest way)

Answer (score 3):

While this is actually valid SQL:

```
select (select A from B where A = D.A ) as C 
from D
```

You are much better-off (performance-wise) implementing a JOIN instead:

```
SELECT D.A
FROM D
INNER JOIN B ON B.A = D.A
```

Comment: I thought about JOIN. But this way will provide difficulties in the future for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean comparing the results of a subquery in a where, Yes you can do this.

`select X ... where (select Y ... ) = Z`

However, probably a bad idea. Generally when you have to do this, it's best to look for a way to streamline it into the main select. There are very creative ways to avoid nested queries. The reason being is that every selection has to do the inner query every time

If you mean performing a where against a subquery, you just select all and apply where. However, again, you could just apply another where.

`select X ... where Y = Z and A = B.`

Comment: I know, that it isn't a good idea, but it is the best solution for my purpose. Thanks for an answer.

Comment: @Eddie I understand that it may seem the best solution. Can I see an example of the query you MUST do nested, so I can see if it can be reworked? Nested is O(n), and that gets impossibly nasty. If the nested query produces the same results every time, there's absolutely no need to use nested.

Comment: I need to create something like "select field1, field2, sql3 as field3, field4, sql5 as field5 from table where field2 = ' ... ', field5 = ' ... '

Comment: @Eddie Use AND to check multiple conditions. OR if either condition is valid. *I don't see a need for a subquery*