# How to use a where clause within a MySQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I am using the following MySQL query to access the latest 20 messages in a chat log and reverse the order so that the latest message is printed on screen last:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            messageID,
            posterID,
            messageTime,
            message
        FROM
            chat_messages
        /* Subquery is used to get the most recent 20 by messageTime */
        ORDER BY 
            messageTime DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) subq
/* Reorder the result of the subquery to put them back into ascending order */
ORDER BY 
    messageTime ASC
```

It works well. The problem is that I am now trying to add groups to the chat functionality. In doing this I have added a further column to the table chat_messages called 'group'. The main chat log is group 0 so I need to change the above query to access only messages from the main chat log. This is where I am stuck. It appears that MySQL will not allow me to add a where clause within the sub-query. I have tried the following and it did not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            messageID,
            posterID,
            messageTime,
            message
        FROM
            chat_messages
        WHERE
            group = '0'
        /* Subquery is used to get the most recent 20 by messageTime */
        ORDER BY 
            messageTime DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) subq
/* Reorder the result of the subquery to put them back into ascending order */
ORDER BY 
    messageTime ASC
```

I get this error message (line 58 is the next line after the query):

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in xxxxxxx on line 58

Following what was written on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590421/mysql-subquery-result-in-where-clause) I tried the following, which also did not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
                (
                    SELECT
                        messageID,
                        posterID,
                        messageTime,
                        message
                    FROM
                        chat_messages
                    WHERE
                        group = '0'
                )
        FROM
            chat_messages
        /* Subquery is used to get the most recent 20 by messageTime */
        ORDER BY 
            messageTime DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) subq
/* Reorder the result of the subquery to put them back into ascending order */
ORDER BY 
    messageTime ASC
```

How can I make the query only access messages from group 0? I just don't understand how it is not working?

Thank you,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for MySQL, place backticks `` ` `` around it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
     SELECT messageID,
          posterID,
          messageTime,
          message
     FROM chat_messages
     WHERE `group` = '0'
        /* Subquery is used to get the most recent 20 by messageTime */
     ORDER BY  messageTime DESC
     LIMIT 20
 ) subq
/* Reorder the result of the subquery to put them back into ascending order */
ORDER BY  messageTime ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that! Such a simple error. Ugh, I spent about 20 minutes wondering why it wasn't working. I'll see myself out. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you use a subquery. The first select is like the second one, except it reverses the order.
When querying MySQL with and ORDER clause, it knows to order them properly.
Given a table (chat) structure like this:
messageID | posterID | messagetTime | message | group | [other fields],
you can select them like this:

`` SELECT messageID, posterId, messageTime, message FROM chat 
WHERE `group` = [number]
ORDER BY messageTIME DESC
LIMIT 20 ``

This will give you the latest 20 messages.
And as @bluefeet said, GROUP is a reserved word and you should use backticks.

Comment: I need to retrieve the last 20 messages and then flip the order so that they are printed on screen in the desired way - with the latest message at the bottom, just above a textarea (like on a smartphone).

Comment: Just traverse the response the other way around :P
`
for (len = response.length(), i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  // code
}`