# Unknown column error in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

Why this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS,a.*,(SELECT cy.iso_code 
                                FROM ps_address AS addr, ps_country AS cy 
                                WHERE addr.id_customer=a.id_customer 
                                AND addr.id_country=cy.id_country) iso_code
FROM `ps_customer` a                        
WHERE iso_code='IT'                         
ORDER BY a.`id_customer` ASC
LIMIT 0,50
```

Return me: `#1054 - Unknown column 'iso_code' in 'where clause'?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation on `SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the `WHERE` clause is executed. See [Section C.5.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

You cannot use column aliases in your `WHERE` clause — you may only use columns that actually exist in one of the tables used in your query.

You could [wrap the subquery so that its result is treated as a "table" in its own right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8590421/560648); then you may apply criteria to that "table".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the iso_code column comes from the ps_address table which is only available in the context of the subquery you are making inside the select list of your main query (ps_customer).

Besides that you don't need this WHERE statement in the main query since you are already restricting the iso_code values in the subquery. Remove it and it should be fine.

Comment: this was also my first suggestion but it is `( SELECT ...) iso_code`

Answer (score 0):

The above SQL won't work because execution starts in following order

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

So that aliases to the columns will be assigned as a second last step in the execution and WHERE happens before it. So SQL engine will never come to know what iso_code is here.

Hope this helps.