# Get values of first record and last record by date in mysql subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb

I know that for some MySQL pro, this is reasonably straightforward.  I further realize that the answer could likely be [figured out from other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590421/mysql-subquery-result-in-where-clause), however I've spent some real time trying to build this query, and I can't seem to figure out how to apply those solutions  to my situation.

Mine *seems different* than others who want the "min and max" of a field - but I need the value from *another field* based on the "min and max" of the date field.

Given the following structure - a "user" table, and an "entries" table:

Data Sample (for "entries" table):

```
id | user_id |     date     | value  
---+---------+--------------+-------
 1         1     2018-02-01     125
 2         5     2018-01-15     220
 3         1     2017-12-31     131
 4         4     2018-01-01      77
 3         1     2017-12-15     133
```

I'd like to know value of the *first entry (by date)*, the value of the *last entry* (by date), and the user_id.

The results should be:

```
user_id | first_date | first_value |  last_date | last_value
--------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------
      1   2017-12-15           133   2018-02-01          125
      4   2018-01-01            77   2018-01-01          133
      5   2018-01-15           220   2018-01-15          220
```

While I want **the best** solution, what I've been working on revolves around combining some queries like so:

```
SELECT user_id, l.date AS last_date, l.value AS last_value, f.date AS first_date, f.value AS first_value  
    FROM user AS u
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, date, value FROM entries ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1) AS f ON f.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, date, value FROM entries ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS l ON l.user_id = u.user_id
```

NOTE: This doesn't work.  If I wanted the "first entry" for someone, I would write a query that was `SELECT user_id, date, value FROM entries ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1` - however, using it in the subqueries doesn't have the desired effect.

I've also tried some `GROUP BY` queries, with no success as well.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71599

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query (feels odd to be pointing this out at 17.5k)

Comment: @fubar - thank you for the fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gives you the expected result, but it's done without using a `LEFT JOIN`. So the `NULL` values are excluded.

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id,
    e1.date AS first_date,
    e1.value AS first_value,
    e2.date AS last_date,
    e2.value AS last_value
FROM 
    users u, 
    (SELECT * FROM entries e ORDER BY date ASC) e1,
    (SELECT * FROM entries e ORDER BY date DESC) e2
WHERE
    e1.user_id = u.id
AND 
    e2.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY 
    u.id
```

And here's a working fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71599/8

Also, it's worth noting that the `LIMIT` in your attempt would limit the results to 1 for all joined results, not each joined result. Either way, the `LEFT JOIN` didn't work. If anyone knows why, I'd be interested to understand.

**Edit:** Here's another attempt, this time utilising `MIN()` and `MAX()`, rather than `ORDER BY`. Unfortunately, you need to join the `entries` table multiple times for this to work though.

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id,
    e1.date AS first_date,
    e1.value AS first_value,
    e2.date AS last_date,
    e2.value AS last_value
FROM users u
INNER JOIN entries e1 ON (u.id = e1.user_id)
INNER JOIN entries e2 ON (u.id = e2.user_id)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS date
    FROM entries
    GROUP BY user_id
) e3 ON (e1.user_id = e3.user_id AND e1.date = e3.date)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM entries
    GROUP BY user_id
) e4 ON (e2.user_id = e4.user_id AND e2.date = e4.date)
GROUP BY u.id
```

Another working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71599/18

Comment: Again - thank you.  Any idea why this would NOT be working on MariaDB via PHPMyAdmin? I'm getting the same records / values for both the "first" and the "last".

Comment: From a quick Google, it sounds like MariaDB ignores `ORDER BY` clauses in subqueries. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @cale_b - I've added another example, which doesn't use `ORDER BY`. That _may_ solve the problem with MariaDB, but I haven't specifically tested it on that RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you so much.  The second example works perfectly (and makes me feel not-quite-so-dumb that I didn't sort it out on my own).