# Error with sql max function: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next sql code that you can see below. It work except last line with where condition.

```
    select m.model,m.price from (
    select product.model, pc.price
    from product
    join pc 
    on product.model=pc.model
    union
    select product.model, laptop.price
    from product
    join laptop 
    on product.model=laptop.model
union
    select product.model, printer.price
    from product
    join printer 
    on product.model=printer.model
    ) m
    where m.price = select max(m.price) from m
```

I have next error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
If I put last line like: `where m.price = m.price` it's also work

Comment: What is your expected output?  Can you include some sample data?

Comment: Give a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590421/mysql-subquery-result-in-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

Are you after the highest price by model?:

```
select m.model,MAX(m.price) as price from 
(
    select product.model, pc.price
    from product
    join pc 
    on product.model=pc.model
    union
    select product.model, laptop.price
    from product
    join laptop 
    on product.model=laptop.model
union
    select product.model, printer.price
    from product
    join printer 
    on product.model=printer.model
    ) m
GROUP BY m.model
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the model with the highest price:

```
select m.model, m.price
from (select p.model, pc.price
      from product p join
           pc 
           on p.model = pc.model
      union all
      select p.model, laptop.price
      from product join
           laptop 
           on p.model = laptop.model
      union all
      select p.model, printer.price
      from product p join
           printer 
           on p.model = printer.model
    ) m
order by m.price desc
limit 1;
```

However, this is way over complicated, because the `join`s are not needed:

```
select m.model, m.price
from (select pc.model, pc.price
      from pc 
      union all
      select laptop.model, laptop.price
      from laptop 
      union all
      select printer.model, printer.price
      from printer 
    ) m
order by m.price desc
limit 1;
```